# Bash: Piping results out to file not working as expected

Tags: bash, shell

I have a tsv file with 3 columns and 7000 rows. It looks like this:

```
1341234jh34h123h    abc 1
23k4j123j4123h4h    abc 1
123j41j234j234jj    bbb 1
1234jj1324j123j4    ccc 1
2134j1234j1234jj    bbb 1
1324j123j4123j41    abc 1
132j412j34j1234j    ddd 1
12j34j1234j4j234    abc 1
12j34j234j123j43    abc 1
123j412j341234jj    abc 1
123j4j234j132j4j    abc 1
123k41k234123l4l    bbb 1
2k134k2134k23k4k    abc 2
132k4k132k423k4k    ddd 1
k234k123k4k34k34    bbb 1
23k4k34k3k43k43k    abc 1
l234k34l3l43;3;4    abc 1
k234k23k42k342k3    bbb 1
q,wmeqwjneqkwjen    ddd 1
llqkweqweqjwejqw    bbb 1
```

My goal is to: take the second column out , sort it and return unique values in a tsv file.

The code that I wrote on the terminal is: `cut -f 2 input.tsv | sort | uniq > output_final.tsv`

It took forever to run this in terminal (`note that the file has 7000 rows`. If you just use the above code on the twenty rows of data provided above, it will be done very quick. )

However, if I do it this in a naive way like below, it is done very fast.

`cut -f 2 input.tsv > output1.tsv`

then

`sort output1.tsv > output2.tsv`

`uniq output2.tsv > output_final.tsv`

So why is the `cut -f 2 input.tsv | sort | uniq > output_final.tsv` code taking forever to run ? Am I writing this wrong ?

**BIG UPDATE:** So I did `time` thing suggested by @paxdiablo. Interestingly, I found that

```
time (cut -f 2 input.tsv >/dev/null)

real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.015s
sys 0m0.002s

time (cut -f 2 input.tsv | sort >/dev/null)

real    0m0.025s
user    0m0.021s
sys 0m0.006s

time (cut -f 2 input.tsv | sort  | uniq >/dev/null)

real    0m0.027s
user    0m0.026s
sys 0m0.008s
```

So, the jobs take tiny amount of time. BUT when I run `cut -f 2 input.tsv | sort >/dev/null`, the terminal just hangs in there like below and not returning anything at all:

```
 chinegro $ > cut -f 2 input.tsv | sort >/dev/null
```

Normally, when the job finishes, the terminal should be like this:

```
chinegro $ > cut -f 2 input.tsv | sort >/dev/null
output blablablalblalblalblalba
chinegro $ >
```

Comment: Your pipe example should work and for 7K lines should be fast.  Can you provide some details about the set-up on your system (uname -a, availible memory etc).

Comment: And specific times for each, rather than "forever" and "very fast".

Comment: @tolanj `uname -a` returns `Darwin Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`. And I was expecting it to be done very fast but it wasn't . @chepner, when I break down the task into separate subtasks, it takes like milliseconds to process the jobs. But when I run the one line code, it takes literally forever and the the job never finishes. This is what i mean by forever.

Answer (score 2):

The pipeline shouldn't make much of a difference.

The first thing I would do is to see which component is causing the problem by running the following commands:

```
time ( cut -f 2 input.tsv >/dev/null )
time ( cut -f 2 input.tsv  | sort >/dev/null)
time ( cut -f 2 input.tsv  | sort | uniq >/dev/null)
```

a few times each and recording the times.

Then you may want to ask a question on [a suitable site](https://stackoverflow.com/) :-) about how to best do the job you want to do, not pre-supposing that `cut`, `sort` and `uniq` will be necessary. Far too many people limit their solution space unnecessarily by stating the tools they're using. You should state *just* the problem and only limit the solution space if absolutely required.

For a start, you could ditch the `uniq` by using `sort -u`, and there may even be a better way using different tools, such as:

```
awk '{keys[$2] = 1} END {for (key in keys) { print key } }' input.tsv
```

---

And, after your update:

```
time (cut -f 2 input.tsv | sort  | uniq >/dev/null)

real    0m0.027s
user    0m0.026s
sys 0m0.008s
```

you can see that it's taking about a thirtieth of a second (user + sys = 0.034s) CPU time.

Hence it's likely that you've gotten something wrong in the original command itself. If it's not returning to the prompt for a *long* time, that's usually indicative that you've left off the input file name, with something like:

```
cut -f 2 | sort
```

and the `cut` will wait forever until you enter some lines then press <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> to indicate end of file (you can test this by entering <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> while it's running and seeing if the prompt returns).

So I would urge you to check your actual command, especially in light of the fact your final one was using `output.tsv` as the *input* file. That's wrong and, if it's a typo, you should double-check that the other commands you've shown us are the *actual* ones you're using.

Comment: @Chinegro, you _won't_ see any output with `>/dev/null`, it's sending the output to the "bit bucket" to remove it's effect on the timings. The fact that the full command executed in (user+sys) about a thirtieth of a second means your issue lies elsewhere. I'll update the answer.

Comment: the file name was only a typo, but I was passing in the correct file. And whether I am output the results to `>/dev/null` or to a file `> output1.tsv`. It still just hangs in there.

Comment: @Chinegro, your comments are conflicted. You state it just hangs but that's not supported by the fact that timing it gave some very small number of seconds, something that can only happen if the process ends.

Comment: This is exactly the problem: timing it gave some very small number of seconds, which means the process must have finished and I did manage to see the output a tsv file. But when I remove `time`, it just hangs in there forever. My question has always been about this conflict.

Answer (score 0):

On my laptop your command on 7000 rows is immediate, but doesn't work since `cut -f 2` doesn't work as expected. This snippet works fast :

```
 while read a b c ; do echo "$b" ; done < input.tsv | sort | uniq >| output_final.tsv
```

The last `>|` stands for overwrite.

Comment: It does the same as `>` but also overwrites the file if it already exists.

Comment: `>|` is only necessary if the `noclobber` option is set.

Comment: Yes but since you don't want to check `nocclober` it is safer to use `>|`.